# how to find exact xml content using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, substring

i hope you could help me with my issue

i need to get the `local-name()` of the node where my string is located

```
var str="the world is complex";

<firsttag>The world is complex.</firsttag>
<secondtag>The world is complex</secondtag>
...
```

this is the code i have:

```
<xsl:if test="$str">
        <xsl:variable name="nodename">
        <xsl:value-of select="local-name([contains(.,$str)])"/>
    </xsl:variable> 
</xsl:if>
```

but this returns the local name of the `<firsttag>` even if it contains a dot(.), i was told that i could validate using`substring-before`and `substring-after` to get the node with the exact string without anything before and after, but i fear that this could have the same results if i have duplicated content in different nodes, but that's not my concern right now.

Comment: It looks like the call to local-name refers to the current context item (and your code doesn't show what that is - but probably not what you want to call local-name on). Please post your complete XSLT code. Also, what language is 'var str="the world is complex";', and how does it interact with XSLT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear. Given the following **test input**:

```
<input>
    <firsttag>The world is complex.</firsttag>
    <secondtag>The world is complex</secondtag>
</input>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="str" select="'The world is complex'"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[.=$str]">
            <elem-name>
                <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            </elem-name>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<output>
   <elem-name>secondtag</elem-name>
</output>
```

If you can be sure that only one input element (at most) matches the condition (or if you're only interested in the name of the *first* element that does so), you can reduce the code to:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:value-of select="name(//*[.=$str])"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>
```

to obtain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<output>secondtag</output>
```

Note that XML is case-sensitive; A string parameter of "the world is complex" will **not** match an element containing "The world is complex".

Comment: i have a specific string and i send it as a parameter to the template, in this case it would be the value in `str` but once i perform the search in the XML, it finds the first node that contains that value, for example, supose that i need to find the node that says `<node>United States</node>`but if i find another node that says `<other_node>United States of America</other_node>` my variable `nodename`will contain `other_node`, i hope this was clear @michael.hor257k

Comment: in this case, `str` would contain "United States", i need the name of the node so i can validate in another template to add some HTML tags, but since i get the first node containing the string but not the exact string, the second validation fails and the HTML tags are not added

Comment: No, I am afraid it's not clear at all. If you use my code above, then a parameter of "United States" will NOT find the node containing "United States of America". Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Yes, i modified my code with the one you provided and it worked perfectly, thanks a lot @michael.hor257k